# Infinite set and proper subset.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that a set A is infinite if and only if $A$ contains a proper subset $B$ that satisfies $|B|=|A|$.

For the first part, I tried the following:
Since $A$ is infinite, it has a countable subset $S=\{a_n\}$ with $n$ in $\mathbb N$. Then we have a function $f:A\to A\setminus \{a_0\}$ such that $f(a_n) = a_{n+1}$ if $a$ is in $A$ and $a=a_n$ and $f(a)=a$ otherwise.

I don't know if this approach is correct, and need help proving part 2.

Comment: I edited your post for formatting and to clarify your definition of $f$. Please check to make sure I edited correctly.

Comment: @AlexBecker thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That approach is excellent: you have indeed shown that if $A$ is infinite, it admits a bijection with a proper subset.

Suppose that $f:A\to A$ is a bijection from $A$ to a proper subset of $A$. Pick $a_0\in A\setminus f[A]$. Given $a_n$, let $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$; now prove that the map $n\mapsto a_n$ is a bijection from $\Bbb N$ into $A$.

Comment: How could I prove part 2 : if there is B such that |B|= |A|, then A is infinite?
I was thinking about using the Schroeder-Bernstein thm.

Comment: @Clayton: I suggested a way in my second paragraph: the existence of such a $B$ is equivalent to the existence of a bijection $f$ from $A$ to a proper subset of $A$.