# If a set $S$ is infinite, then it can be put in 1-1 correspondence with proper subset.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a problem from Curtis' *Abstract Linear Algebra.* We have the following definition of infinite set:

> A set $T$ is infinite if it contains a subset $U\subseteq T$ which can be put into a one-to-one correspondence with $\mathbb N$.

The problem asks to use the bijection $\sigma:\mathbb N\to 2\mathbb N$ given by $\sigma(n)=2n$ in order to prove that

> If a set $S$ is infinite, then it can be put in a one-to-one correspondence with a proper subset of itself.

If $S$ is countably infinite, then I don't have a problem showing this. I just make a composition $S\to\mathbb N\to 2\mathbb N\to U$ where we take $U$ to be the subset of $S$ whose elements are those $s\in S$ which correspond to even $n\in\mathbb N$.

But how do I use $\sigma$ in the case that $S$ is uncountable? I can find an injection $U\to S$ and a surjection $S\to U$, but no bijection. I have looked at the following, but I do not have the requisite knowledge for most of the answers and I don't see how I can use them in relation to this problem (in that I must use $\sigma)$:

1. [Infinite set and proper subset.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203200/infinite-set-and-proper-subset)
2. [Set contains a proper infinite subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439639/set-contains-a-proper-infinite-subset?rq=1)
3. http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Infinite_Set_Equivalent_to_Proper_Subset

Comment: Just define $\sigma(x) = x$ for all $x\notin V$, where $V \subset S$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: Why are you redefining $\sigma$? Perhaps you could elaborate and post as an answer, rather than a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S$ be any infinite set, then there is a subset $U \subset S$, and a bijection
$$
\tau : U \to \mathbb{N}
$$
Now define $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by $n \mapsto 2n$, and consider the map $\tau^{-1}\circ f\circ \tau : U \to U$. This is a 1-1 correspondence between $U$ and a subset of $U$. Now define $\sigma : S\to S$ by
$$
\sigma(s) = \begin{cases}
\tau^{-1}\circ f \circ \tau(s) &: s\in U \\
s &: s\notin U \\
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\sigma : S\to S$ is a 1-1 correspondence between $S$ and a subset of $S$.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification!